# Why my files(photos) are in untracked files?

Tags: git, git-untracked

I added few photos to my project `.png` and `.svg`, and for some reason (not in ignore file) they are getting into the untracked files list.

Is this any reason for it? How Git chooses the files to untrack?

Comment: You should `git add` files that you want to track.

Comment: but every new photo goes to the untracked list and not to unstaged
isn't it supose to go to unstaged?

Comment: It's not only images; it's every new file you add. You should do `git add` on each file you want to track, by default they are untracked.

Comment: You can write `git add .` to add all files.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a new file to your project, by default new file are untrack.

```
git add 'myfile'
```

Comment: I'm using  source tree as UI, is there a reason why he doesn't shows those files ?

Comment: @AviMoraly maybe this will help you : https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/32966716/how-to-track-new-added-files-in-sourcetree-app